# Render a custom page in ActiveAdmin using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have seen the following page: 
http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-custom-pages.html

It doesn´t have a lot of information on how to create a custom page.

What I need to do is to add a custom action to the index of an entity that redirects me to another page i.e. /admin/mycustompage . I want to render my new page from a partial. It has to look similar to a view or edit page (with a breadcrumb and the layout).

The example in the docs is too simple:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "My Page" do
    content do
      para "Hello World"
    end
end
```

How can I render a partial within the content?
How can I render the breadcrumb?
How is the url for this new page specified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sample page, rendering /app/views/admin/password/_index.html.haml partial:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Password" do

  menu label: I18n.t("menu.change_password")

  content do
    render "index"
  end

end
```

Default url for this page is /admin/password (you can check it by calling 'rake routes').
If your page title contains spaces, you have to use aa version from github, because it was impossible until this commit - https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/30b19c86eef3c504fe71c2e39e072620169b80c2

Comment: Would be nice to able to control where it looks for the partial.  The default seems to want you to create a folder for every page with a single index.html in it.  Ugh.

Comment: @odigity - convention over configuration